# Set input Fields in Pristine and empty values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

my function is reacting some how strange, it doesnt makes much sense. Basically i implemented a directive in a input field, i used ngChange, and basicalyl what it happens is of the value in that input field gets empty the input field its set to $pristine.

The strange part is regarding with empty input fields, above i leave my code:

```
 function changeProfitable(){  
           if(typeof vm.profitability == 'undefined'){
               vm.wantedProfitability = "";
               $scope.form.profitability.$setPristine=true;
            }

 }
```

For example in the if statement instead of putting "typeof ...." and put vm.profitability = "123", the function works fine, but when i use "typeof vm.profitability == 'undefined'" to check if the input field is empty, the function still runs the if statement, but the inputfield isnt set to $pristine.

Cant figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set pristine state on the form control. You can set form to pristine state with

```
$scope.form.$setPristine();
```

And you can check if something is undefined with angular.isUndefined() function.

Comment: Already tried it and still not working, for some reason it works if i insert and then delete from the controller, but if i delete by using backspace it doesnt react the same way.